# ExtJS store with data-bound URL not re-evaluating data properties

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewmodel

I've an ExtJS 5 ViewModel which contains a store, with a JSON reader using an AJAX proxy.

The URL of the proxy however relies on binding, which substitutes in ViewModel data properties.  However it appears that the evaluation of the URL property is done only the first time the ViewModel loads, and not when the data property changes.

This code should illustrate what I'm trying to do, even though its missing parts (extends statements, etc.) for brevity in this post.

**I define my view model with a store:**

```
    Ext.define('sample.ViewModel',{
            extend:'Ext.app.ViewModel',
          data:{
            departmentId:0,
            categoryId:0
          }

            stores:{
                myItems:{
                    autoLoad:false,
                    fields:['id','name','price'],
                    proxy:{
                        type:'ajax',
                        url:'/items/department/{departmentId}/category/{categoryId}',
                        reader:{
                            rootProperty:'data',
                            successProperty:'success'
                        }
                    }   
                }
            }
    }
```

**Then a view with a grid:**
(columns, etc. removed for brevity)

```
    Ext.define('sample.View',{
        // ....
        items:[{
            xtype:grid,
            bind:'{myItems}'
        }]

    }
```

**And a controller who changes the view model data properties and reloads the store:**

```
    Ext.define('sample.ViewController',{
        // ...
        handleSomeEvent:function(){
            var viewModel = this.getViewModel();
            var store       = viewModel.getStore('myItems');

            viewModel.set('departmentId', 3);
            viewModel.set('categoryId', 4);

            // Desired behavior
            store.load();

            // Required workaround
            viewModel.bind('/items/department/{departmentId}/category/{categoryId}', function(newUrl){
                store.load({url: newUrl})
            });
        }
    });
```

Without the "required workaround" in the controller logic the store / grid always tries to pull data from /items/department/0/category/0 (i.e. the ViewModel data values at the time that the ViewModel is instantiated).

I'd like to know how to force ExtJS to re-evaluate config properties (i.e. the proxy URL) when the ViewModel data properties change.

Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're having is that the ViewModel ticks on a timer. By the time you call `load`, it's not evaluated the calls to `set`. If it didn't, you'd have the binding trigger twice, once when you set the `departmentId`, then a second time when you set the `categoryId`.

You can force the ViewModel to tick by calling `notify`:

```
viewModel.set('departmentId', 3);
viewModel.set('categoryId', 4);
viewModel.notify();
store.load();
```

Comment: Marvelous, worked a treat, much thanks for the very quick reply!

Comment: any way to do this without using a private method in Ext?